# How to copy EMF images from .NET Windows.Forms into Visio?

Tags: .net, winforms, clipboard, vector-graphics

I am working on a diagram editor written in .NET 2.0 using Windows.Forms.
Diagrams must be copied into Microsoft Word and Visio *as vector graphics*.

The editor has a *Save as EMF* function that works: Word and Visio can import the resulting file as a vector graphics image.  The code is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521541/how-to-draw-a-rotated-text-in-a-meta-file).

I am now adding a *Copy as EMF* function to support direct copy and paste into Word and Visio,
using the same `System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile` used in the *Save as EMF* function.

Copying it onto the clipboard using `SetData(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile, ...)` produces a result that Word claims it can paste as EMF, but shows up empty. The documentation [explains this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.enhancedmetafile%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and provides [a workaround using unmanaged API functions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323530). I have copied that code.

Now the EMF image shows up when pasted into Word, but it doesn't when pasted into Visio!
When I paste it into Word, then copy it there and paste it into Visio, it also shows up there.

How can I make this work?

- What is Word doing that my code is not?
- Why does the route via a file work without unmanaged API calls, but not the route via the clipboard?
- Why do I need unmanaged objects (handles) in the first place?
- Is there any self-contained documentation I can read to understand these issues without having to learn Win32 programming?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you may want to have a look at [this Diagram editor example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819318/how-to-create-and-connect-custom-user-buttons-controls-with-lines-using-windows/15821573#15821573) I made in a couple of hours in current Windows Desktop Technologies.